# Log levels in Nginx: NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP vs NGX_LOG_DEBUG

Tags: nginx, logging, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am inspecting some Nginx code, in particular the code for [Nginx module - upstream health check](https://github.com/alibaba/tengine/blob/master/modules/ngx_http_upstream_check_module/ngx_http_upstream_check_module.c). At some places I see `NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP` as the logging level, at others `NGX_LOG_DEBUG`. Could someone tell me which logging level is recommended to be used in which scenario?

Answer (score 2):

This [link](https://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#logging) has the required information. Here are few scenarios to explain how it works:

If your `nginx.conf` has log level defined as the generic `debug`

`error_log error.log debug;`

then all your logging statments with debug levels prefixed with `NGX_LOG_DEBUG` will be logged. For e.g.

`ngx_log_debug(NGX_LOG_DEBUG, event->log, 0, "test");
    ngx_log_debug(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP, event->log, 0, "test");
    ngx_log_debug(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_CORE, event->log, 0, "test");`

But if your `nginx.conf` is configured to log a specific kind of debug message, only those will be logged.

So, with this config:

`error_log error.log debug_http;`

this will happen:

```
ngx_log_debug(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_CORE, event->log, 0, "test"); //will not show up in the log
ngx_log_debug(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP, event->log, 0, "test"); //will show up in the log
```